# how to select particular rows and columns without hardcoding in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to select name and score from index 1 to 3 and store it to a dataframe. Can we extract that without hardcoding by giving a start word and end word.

```py
import pandas as pd

name_dict = {
            'Name': ['a','b','c','d', 'e'],
            'Score': ['0.90(subject to approval)',80,95,20,10]
          }

df = pd.DataFrame(name_dict)

print (df)
df.set_index('Name').loc['a', 'Score']
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `iloc`:

```
>>> df.iloc[1:4]
  Name Score
1    b    80
2    c    95
3    d    20
```

Comment: Hi Corralien, Can we use the logic on Name instead of index 1-4

Comment: Like `df.set_index('Name').loc['b':'e'].reset_index()`?

Comment: Hi Corralien, I've a doubt. Let's say I don't know the value of e or 4th index. How can I get value of index 1,2,3. Can we solve that by using a stopword?

Comment: What do you mean by a stopword?

Comment: stopword in the sense Name e or the last value in row. by this we can filter contents in between.

Comment: Something like: `df.loc[df[df['Name'] == 'b'].index[0]:df[df['Name'] == 'e'].index[0]]`?

Comment: Hi corralien, not like the above. can we specify some string keyword in code so that the code know where to start/stop and extract in dataframe. The advantage is even though data changes in order, then this method would work.

Comment: I don't know why my previous comment does not fit your need? Maybe `start, stop = pd.Index(df['Name']).get_indexer_for(['b', 'e']); df.iloc[start:stop]`?

Comment: Hi Corralien, Your previous code and this also works. Thanks mate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246164/discussion-between-ak007-and-corralien).